# argument escaping from command line (perl)

Tags: perl, unix

I'm a `perl` noob here and was wanting to run this from the command line of my unix machine.

```
./myprog.pl $str1 str2
```

Where I need to replace `str2` with `str1`. Trouble is that I don't know how to escape from the `$` in the `str1` argument.  I tried looking on here and on other websites but I couldnt find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What shell? Is that the bourne-shell or a derivative, then both of the following will pass `$str1` and `str2` to the program.

```
./myprog.pl '$str1' str2

./myprog.pl \$str1 str2
```

---

But you talk of "replacing". Is the first arg suppose to be a regex pattern that matches `$str1`? If so, then you can use either of the following:

```
./myprog.pl '\$str1' str2

./myprog.pl \\\$str1 str2
```

This escapes `$` for the regex engine (by adding a `\`), then escapes the `\` and `$` for the shell (by adding quotes or extra `\`s).

Comment: Yes I'm using bash. For some reason it's not doing anything with the argument when I surround it with ' ' or start with \. It just outputs $str1.

I guess my next question is how does $str1 get it's value?

Comment: huh? Strings don't get values.